# PHP - Upload CSV file and import to database, where table doesnt exist

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I need to create a PHP file that will take a text file containing a LOT of data, and import it into a MySQL database.

I know I can do this by opening the file, parsing it, and using individual commands per line to insert the data.

But I want to know if there is a way to do this if the MySQL table doesn't exist first.

I am trying to automate the process as much as possible, to remove time and potential human error.

So, is it possible to specify a text file (it is a CSV file, but the data is separated by '|' instead of commas) in PHP, and have the PHP script first create the MySQL table, and then import the full data file into that table?

The first line of the text file will always contain the column names.

I know I could do this by opening the file, taking the first line, using that to create a table, and then going back and looping through the file again, inserting data a line at a time - but I want to know if there is a quicker and more efficient way of handling the files than that!

The files are really large, so the method needs to be as efficient as possible, and I feel that there may be a command that I am not aware of??

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` is by far the best option for large files.

Comment: are you looking for `create table` ? [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) is the manual.

Comment: Not saying you're doing this wrong, but just a heads up; creating tables during runtime is usually considered *very* bad practice. Have you considered using an EAV approach or something like that? I assume this is not just a one-time batch script.

Comment: This is an internal script that needs to be used daily each morning to upload new data. So my thought was to create new table, upload new data, check new data, delete current table, rename new table to current - and to do this all automatically if possible!!

Comment: @Daan This was the most helpful suggestion. I ended up using a combination of CREATE TABLE and LOAD DATA INFILE, but your suggestion of LOAD DATA INFILE was the most helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Like

```
mysqlimport  --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=,
--columns='ID,foo,bar' --local -u root -p
Database /path/to/csvfile/TableName.csv
```

For creating the actual table, you should just use a query for that before you import the data. With the query you can specify about anything to create the table, columns and datatypes etc.